# Как получить наименьшее значение не учитывая NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

Хотел бы воспользоваться функцией `LEAST` в процедуре, чтобы найти наименьшее значение.

Проблема в том, что некоторые из значений могут быть `NULL`, и если делаю так:

```
select least(NULL,0,1) from dual
```

Получаю `NULL`, что скорее всего, верно, но не то, что ожидаю получить.

Как получить действительно наименьшее значение игнорируя `NULL`?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Least value but not NULL in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21313770) от участника [@Jestem-z-Kozanowa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034761/jestem-z-kozanowa)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/21313770

Answer (score 3):

Если какой-то аргумент NULL, то взять наименьший из остальных аргументов. Если все аргументы NULL, то вернуть NULL.

Можно воспользоваться для двух аргументов чем то вроде этого:

```
LEAST (NVL(colA,colB), NVL(colB,colA))
```

Но если более двух аргументов, то это становиться не очень красиво:

```
LEAST (COALESCE(colA,colB,colC),
       COALESCE(colB,colA,colC),
       COALESCE(colC,colA,colB))
```

В этом случае, возможно начать рассматривать "магические значения". Но это может быть ошибкой, например, если один из аргументов вдруг действительно равен "магическому значению".

```
SELECT CASE WHEN result = maxval THEN NULL ELSE r END AS result
FROM (
    SELECT LEAST(NVL(:colA,maxv), 
                 NVL(:colB,maxv), 
                 NVL(:colC,maxv)) AS result, maxval
    FROM (
        SELECT 9.999999999999999999999999999999999999999e125 AS maxval FROM DUAL));
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325947) от участника [@Jeffrey Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Самый подходящий случай, создать свою кастомную функцию:

```
with function leastIgnoreNulls (args numlist) return int is
    ret int;
begin
    for n in 1..args.count loop
        if args(n) is null then continue; end if;
        ret := case when args(n) > coalesce (ret, args(n)) then ret else args(n) end;
    end loop;
    return ret;
end leastIgnoreNulls;
select leastIgnoreNulls (numlist (null, 9, null, 3, 7)) result from dual
/

    RESULT
----------
         3
```

Так как, предполагается использование в PL/SQL процедуре, то и поместить функцию туда:

```
create or replace procedure proc is
    res int;
    
    function leastIgnoreNulls (args numlist) return int is
        ret int;
    begin [тело функции, см. выше]
    end leastIgnoreNulls;
begin
    res := leastIgnoreNulls (numlist (null, 9, null, 3, 7)); 
end;
/
```